# How to programmatically add shortcut to Windows desktop for Web App in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I can create a Desktop (and Start Menu ) shorcut to a webapp from within Chrome manually (instructions below)

Is there any way to do that *for the user* ?

1. Go to www.TheWebsite.com in Chrome
2. Click "Login"
3. Click on the "settings" icon in the upper right hand corner of Chrome - it looks like 3 bold horizontal lines, one above the other, all the same length.
4. On the menu which drops down from this button, put your cursor on "Tools," which will cause "Tools" to expand.  The top choice is "Create application Shortcuts" - click this.
5. It will open a window which says, "Create application shortcuts," and will have a box with "MoreSpeech Web App" and then "Create application shortcuts in the following places:"
   Desktop (check this for sure)
   Start menu (click if you like, not necessary)
   Quick launch bar (also optional)
6. Click "create"